# Custom background xml file

Tags: android

Is it possible to make xml file with background, that will contain 3 vertical lines of color (black 10 dp, white match_parent, black 10 dp)?

I need to use it as xml file in background property of layout, so i can not simple divide that layout into 3 parts and color them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this...

Create a **background.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/id_view"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/id_view_one"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:background="@android:color/black"/>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/id_view_two"
            android:layout_below="@+id/id_view_one"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/white"/>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/id_view_three"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@android:color/black"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

*Then include the background.xml in your required xml file as below,*

**your_activity.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/id_view"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <include layout="@layout/back"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I already made it with picture (long story, but i need only bottom corners to be 100% transparent and grey middle for background. 
But that should work, so i mark as answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use 9-patch generator to create 9 patch images:

Essentially, the 9-patch generator will accept an image with any size you have and will create resources which stretch specific areas of your image and content.  Then you can easily import them.
link: https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html#&sourceDensity=320&name=example

Answer (score 0):

I usually use this code to add a horizontal line:

```
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
```

To add a vertical separator, switch the layout_width and layout_height values.